# difference between du command and apache FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory

Tags: java, du, fileutils

I do a simple `du -sh` on `/etc/` directory it shows me 11M. But when I use:

```
System.out.println(FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(new File("/etc/"))));
```

This shows me: 68 MB. Is this bug? Or I'm missing something.

**[UPDATE]**

When I use `du -shL`(L for dereference symbolic links) it shows me 77M.